# Have an error when loading .js or .json model in project

Tags: three.js, blender

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "models/1.json", function( geometry ) {
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();
var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( object );
});
```

Took this code from three.js/doc. And when launch in browser ,seeing  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in JSONLoader.js:171. Im using three js r70

Comment: I get older version of blender exporter and i make .js model with him help.Now all working

Answer (score 0):

Line 171 would have been for the `vertices` array. Did you not check the `Vertices` option when exporting? Did you possibly export a Scene and not a Geometry format?